# List.js - filtering by an attribute with more than 1 key/value/answer

Tags: javascript, filter, listjs, list.js

I'm trying to filter a List.js list by a data-attribute where the result has **multiple** answers:

```
 <div data-colors="red, blue, green">Item Name</div>
```

When I try the following it wont search through each item:

```
 $('.filter').on('click',function(){
   var $q = $(this).attr('data-colors');

   if($(this).hasClass('active')){
      myList.filter();
      $('.filter').removeClass('active');
   } else {
     myList.filter(function(item) {
        if (item.values().colors == $q) {
           return true;
        } else {
           return false;
        }
      });
      $('.filter').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
   }
});
```

If I try it when there is only **one** result, then it works fine:

```
 <div data-colors="red">Item Name</div>
```

I have tried various options to filter through each item, but nothing seems to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: it's because the data colors is a string. you should split the colors and check if array contains color instead of == data color

Comment: `var $q = $(this).attr('data-colors').split(', ');`   ...   `item.values().colors.some(x=>$q.some(y=>y==x))` or every depending on if they all have to be included

Answer (score 1):

I just did this analysis for a customer's project.  We wanted a simple checkbox input system. The dilemma was individual elements within the Unordered list could have multiple roles (data-colors).  I chose a single binary value to represent this.  The filter used a simple Bitwise AND function.  This worked well.

Complete Code [is here.](https://github.com/zipzit/Boolean_OR_Filter_Test)

Demo, [via CodeSandBox is here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/zipzit/Boolean_OR_Filter_Test)  Be sure to look at console logs to understand the filtering transactions.

Key functions are here:

```
        var teamKey = 16 + 8 + 4 + 2 + 1;

        function OnChangeCheckbox(checkbox, listObj) {
            if (checkbox.checked) {
                console.log("The check box is checked. " + checkbox.value);
                teamKey += parseInt(checkbox.value, 10);
            } else {
                console.log("The check box is not checked.");
                // remove value from teamArray
                teamKey -= parseInt(checkbox.value, 10);
            }
            console.log("teamKey: " + dec2bin(teamKey));
            listObj.filter(filterList);
        }

        function filterList(item) {
            console.log("indiv value: ", dec2bin(item.values().teams), " teamKey: ", dec2bin(teamKey) )
            console.log( "     Bitwise And: ", dec2bin(item.values().teams & teamKey));

            if (item.values().teams & teamKey) {  // the magic is here
                console.log("    pass: ", item.values().teams & teamKey);
                return true;
            } else {
                console.log("    fail: ", item.values().teams & teamKey);
                return false;
            }
        }
```

The list element `<div class="teams">XX</div>` would be hidden via CSS `display: none;` in use.